# curl escapar de valores de parámetros junto con envío de ficheros en la misma petición

Tags: post, curl

Estoy intentando realizar una petición `POST` con el comando `curl` enviando en la misma petición fichero y campos en formato `clave = valor`. 
Mi problema es de qué manera se puede escapar el valor de un parámetro que empieza por el carácter `@` para que se pueda diferenciar del envío de un fichero.

Ejemplo:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/Tickets/sendContent -F 'inputFile=@/tmp/ticket01.xml' -F'user=username' -F'password=@password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el problema puedes usar la opción [--data-urlencode](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode), tu llamada quedaría así:

```
curl -F "inputFile=@/tmp/ticket01.xml" -F"user=username" --data-urlencode password=@password http://localhost:8080/Tickets/sendContent
```

Otra forma podría ser usando Entity codes, así:

```
@ = %40

curl -F "inputFile=@/tmp/ticket01.xml" -F"user=username" -F "password=%40password" http://localhost:8080/Tickets/sendContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Los entity codes son reemplazados en peticiones GET pero en una petición POST llega tal cual.
También había probado la opción --data-urlencode y el curl me devolvía el siguiente error: Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!

La solución ha sido utilizar en lugar de la opción -F en el campo que contiene la '@' y que no es un fichero la opción --form-string que mantiene literalmente el valor que pasa al parámetro:
curl http://localhost:8080/Tickets/sendContent -F 'inputFile=@/tmp/ticket01.xml' -F'user=username' --form-string'password=@password'